# How do I use PHP regex to ignore some HTML if it exists?

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm writing some PHP that will scrape a webpage and return a very small value from it when it exists.

The HTML that I will receive sometimes looks like:

```
<!-- message -->
<div id="post_message_5400147">
<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->

<!-- END TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->
                ss:<font size="5"><b><font size="5"><font size="5"> U71</font></font></b></font>
</div>
<!-- / message -->
```

Sometimes it will look like:

```
<!-- message -->
<div id="post_message_5400147">

    ss:<font size="5"><b><font size="5"><font size="5"> U71</font></font></b></font>
</div>
<!-- / message -->
```

And sometimes it will look like:

```
<div id="post_message_5400752">

    Bonus code: SKATE
</div>
<!-- / message -->
```

The difference being the the '<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE....' stuff in the first example, and the "Bonus code: ..." text in the third.

What I want the regex to do is only return '<!-- message's where the text is "ss:[...]" (sometimes it can also be "ss=[...]").  Ideally it would strip out all of the extraneous HTML and *just* return the 3 character seat ("U71" in the example; always in the form of LETTERnumnum) but I don't really care too much about that as I can always strip_tags() it out later.

So far, this is what I've been able to figure out (I'm very new to regex) but it doesn't ignore the "Bonus code:[...]" entries:

```
preg_match('/.*<!-- message -->\s*<div id="post_message_[0-9]{7}">\s*(.*?)<!-- \/ message -->/s', $html, $matches);
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this more elegantly since obviously I'm not doing it right?

Comment: $domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);$text=trim($domd->getElementsByTagName("div")[0]->textContent);   ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use something simple like this:

```
$p = '/> (\w{1}\d{2})</';
```

example:

```
$s = <<<EOT
 <!-- message -->
 <div id="post_message_5400147">
 <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->
 <!-- END TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->
    ss:<font size="5"><b><font size="5"><font size="5"> U71</font></font></b></font>
 </div>
 <!-- / message -->
EOT;

$p = '/> (\w{1}\d{2})</';
preg_match($p,$s,$m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

output:

```
U71
```

To find all matches and get the last one you can do something like:

```
$s = "<test> U71</test>some junk here <span> Z23</span>";
$p = '/> (\w{1}\d{2})</';
preg_match_all($p,$s,$m);
var_dump(end($m[1]));
```

output:

```
Z23
```

The [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function will advance the array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

Comment: This is so awesome, but my question is: if there are multiple entries on the same page (I'm scraping a forum post since they don't have an API), will this always return the last/most recent one?

Comment: You can use `preg_match_all()` to get all the occurences and then get that last item off the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: scraping html with regex.. is probably a bad idea in the first place

Comment: Possibly, but your method will most likely always return unexpected results.